# How to save a table in Matlab into a table in database?

Tags: sql-server, matlab

I extract all the rows from a database table into a table in Matlab,
I make changes in some cells. Now I want to save the content of the Matlab table back into the database table. How can I do it?

The database is SqlServer. The table is a Table in Matlab, which is an exact extraction of a table in Sqlserver database. I am using Matlab version 2014b and datbase toolbox.

```
SQL = select pr from prices
conn = database('mydb', '', '', 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver','jdbc:sqlserver://myserver; database=mydb;integratedSecurity=true;');
setdbprefs('DataReturnFormat','table')
e = exec(conn,SQL)
myprices = e.Data
```

Then I made changes in myprices, which is a table and mirror the table in the database, and I would like to save it back to the database.

Thanks a lot.

Jen

Comment: How are you reading the database into the table?

Comment: We need more information about the database and the type of objects. Please edit your question to include the code you already have.

Comment: If your database is a textfile in a folder, you can probably use `fscanf`

Comment: Edited my original post and code. Please help. Thank you!

Comment: For some reason the new line is not working for me. so I use ";". The code should look like: SQL = 'select pr from prices ; conn = database('mydb', '', '', 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver','jdbc:sqlserver://myserver;database=mydb;integratedSecurity=true;'); setdbprefs('DataReturnFormat','table'); e = exec(conn,SQL); myprices = e.Data

Answer (score 0):

From the MATLAB table you should be able to extract column names as cell array, similarly for each row of your table, then use fastinsert() as described in this link: http://fr.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/fastinsert.html

Comment: Hi,  I read the link and tried. But my table has a column in string, yet my database table needs datetime, so I keep getting error: "Error using database/fastinsert (line 90)
Variable fields and insert fields do not match." and I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Please someone help. Cristea?